# Using Hypodermic with Boost.Signals2

Tags: signals-slots, boost-signals, boost-signals2, hypodermic

In order to use Boost.Signals2 with Hypodermic, how would I go about connecting the slots? Would I place the connection code within the OnActivating block?

Am I right in thinking they are not duplicating each others functionality even though Hypodermic is built with Signals2?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you give a pseudo-code sample?

Comment: By the way, Hypodermic is not using Boost.Signals2.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting the signal(s) in OnActivating will not "fire" the signal; that is, your signal's delegates won't be invoked.

But of course, you can do something like this to make it work:

```
mySignal.connect([](std::shared_ptr< Foo > foo)
{
    // do some stuff with Foo being activated
}); 

builder.autowireType< Foo >()->onActivating(
    [&mySignal](IActivatingData< Foo >& data)
    {
        // invoke all delegates...
        mySignal(data.instance());
    }
);
```

Hope that helps.